# Is it expected for poll() to take 40ms to return even though data will be available sooner?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I created a proxy server to handle CQL orders from website clients. The proxy listens for incoming connections and each connection is given a thread. The thread loops as long as the socket exists and dies on `HUP`. You may also stop the proxy, which will stop the threads by sending an event (See [eventfd()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd)) to each thread.

By itself, this already allows me to save a good 100ms because the proxy is local and connecting to a local service is much faster than a service on a remote computer... (even if the computer is local.)

However, I send orders and once in a while the proxy sees no incoming data (i.e. it calls `read()` on the socket which is setup as `NONBLOCK` and gets **-1** in return and `errno == EAGAIN`.) When that happens, I call `poll()` to wait for additional data, the `HUP`, or a *hit* on the `eventfd` meaning I have to quit (i.e. 2 fds, the socket and the `eventfd`).

Somehow, more often than not, when I hit the `poll()` function call, it adds an extra 40ms to the time it takes for a message to go round trip. Although one would think this only happens on larger messages, it happens when I receive an order, which is less than 100 bytes! So the size should not be the culprit. I also changed the code to make sure I send the entire order from the client to the proxy in one `write()` and to avoid the `poll()` if at all possible (i.e. I call `read()` first, and `poll()` only if nothing is available.)

Note that I have no timeout in this case because there is nothing to check other than the incoming orders and the `eventfd`. So I would imagine that the timeout won't be a problem.

The code base is really big. But the client/server comes down to something like this (the sizes in original are fully dynamic):

```
// Client
...
connect(socket);
...
write(socket, order, sizeof(order));
read(socket, result, sizeof(result));
// repeat for other orders, as required by client...


// server
...
socket = accept(); // happens for each client
...
pthread_create(runner);
...

// server thread (runner)
...
for(;;)
{
  int r(0);
  for(;;)
  {
    r += read(socket, order, sizeof(order));
    if(r >= sizeof(order))
    {
      break;
    }
    // wait for more data is not enough received yet
    poll(..."socket" + "eventfd"...);  // <-- this will often take 40ms
    if(eventfd_happened)
    {
      // quit thread
      return;
    }
  }
  ...
  [work on order]
  ...
  write(socket, result, sizeof(result));
}
```

Note 1: I see the problem when I have a single client. So having multiple clients does not in itself cause the problem either.

Note 2: The client really uses BIO_connect(), BIO_read() and BIO_write() [from OpenSSL], but I doubt that would be a problem. I do not use any kind of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you're using non-blocking I/O given you have a dedicated thread per socket. Just block in `read()`. Use `SO_RCVTIMEO` if you need an overall read timeout.

Comment: `poll(..."socket" + "eventfd"...)` -- he's listening on two sockets, so a blocking read on one of them would be wrong.

Comment: @kfsone, if I could eliminate the eventfd which I use to cleanly leave the thread, then it would work by blocking on the `read()`.

Comment: You can stop a thread that is blocked in a `read()` by shutting down the socket for input, which will cause the `read()` to return zero as though the peer had closed the connection; or by using a read timeout and testing a flag.

Comment: @kfsone No he isn't. He has one thread doing `accept()` and another doing `read()` and `poll()` on just the one socket.

Comment: Okay, I could indeed remove the eventfd and use blocking sockets and thus remove the poll(). It feels like more calls work faster, yet some are still taking the 40ms pause... Well... I guess that must be because of all the other things going on at the same time (I have between 10 and 13 items started in parameter, with just 4 processors, so it could just be way that computer works.)

Comment: More calls can't work faster, whatever you may feel about it.

Comment: @EJP Again, it's in his code, he's polling two sockets: `poll(..."socket" + "eventfd"...)`.

Comment: @kfsone You did a better job of deciphering the pseudo-code than I did, but OP has stated the `eventfd` is only for waking up the thread, and I've shown how to do that properly. The thread is really only handling one socket, so blocking I/O is indicated.